# What is the basis for $V+W$ and $V\cap W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W = \langle(1,-1,2,1)\rangle$ and $V = \{(x,y,z,t)\ |\ x+y-z-t=0\}$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. What is the basis for $V+W$ and $V\cap W$?

Answer (score 2):

Everything in $W$ is of the form $(a,-a,2a,a)$.  But
$$
a+(-a)-2a-a=0
$$
only when $a=0$.  Thus $V\cap W=\{0\}$.  Thus a basis for $V+W$ is just a basis for $V$ along with a basis for $W$.

Comment: And the basis for $V\cap W$ is $\emptyset$, in case it wasn't obvious from $V\cap W=\{\emptyset\}$.