# Find basis of the subspaces $U$, $W$, $U + W$, $U \cap W$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck in this linear algebra problem, can you please help me solve it? (I have no idea what to do here!)

In a linear space $\Bbb R^4$

$a_1 = (-3, 2, 21, -14)$

$a_2 = (−6, 1, 3, 0),$

$a_3 = (−3, −1, 2, 3)$

$U = l(a_1, a_2, a_3)$

$W$ is a system $=$

$$− 8x_1 + x_2 − 4x_3 + 7x_4 = 0$$
$$13x_1 − 13x_2 + 17x_3 − 7x_4 = 0$$
$$− 3x_1 + 2x_2 − 3x_3 + 2x_4 = 0$$

Find the basis of the subspaces $U, W, U + W, U \cap W$

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at some other similar questions (and answers) to see whether this helps you with this one:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259178
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554251
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598880
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059700
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086386
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398300
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858396
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095395 (You can probably find a few more in the list of related questions on the right.)